# Pin Verification In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm a beginner. I have a pin field in my user database. I want users to verify the pin before they can access there profile. how can I do this any logic?

in livewire components

```
public function verify (){
  $user = User::select('id')->where('pin',$pin)->first();
  Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
  return redirect()->intended('/user');
}

in my livewire blade I will call the verify method in the form will this work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**laravel login using pincode** :check the following code example may be you get the hint how to implement that, in this example code pin authentication is  done using JWT and then user is allowed to access to those specific routes.

```
$user = User::find($uid);

try {
    if (!$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) {
        return $this->onUnauthorized();
    }
} catch (JWTException $e) {
    return $this->onJwtGenerationError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For somereason if you dont want to use the above JWT method you can use this one. i'm sharing the code for an example from by program which may help you

```
$user = User::select('id')->where('pin',$pin)->first();
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
return redirect()->intended('/user');
```

Comment: how will I check this via the user pin form?

Comment: You can send the simple request using POST method via form or if you are building a dynamic app then can use ajax based dynamic form request in both cases you can use the above code you validate that pin from database and auth the user

Comment: sorry please the form must have the pin as name then I will send form to the Verify method check up I have updated my question

Comment: you also need to add a check flag here too because if user is unable to need the flag condition he will not be allowed to view the dashboard
for live wire you can bind it with wire model check it against the flag condition and if flag passed then user will be authenticated else he get an error of pin validation which you can display via livewire component